# If q prime then $A/f^{-1} (q) $ is isomorphic to a subring of $B/q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I need to understand or prove the following statement: "If $f: A\rightarrow B $ is a ring homomorphism and $q$ is a prime ideal in B, then
$f^{-1} (q)$ is a prime ideal in $A$, for $A/f^{-1} (q) $ is isomorphic to a subring of $B/q$ and hence has no zero-divisor $\neq 0$". I can not find this result among the isomorphism theorems about rings.
I do not understand why $A/f^{-1} (q) $ is isomorphic to a subring of $B/q$. In case $q=Ker(f),$ then $A/f^{-1} (q)$ would be isomorphic to Im$ f.$ I also do not understand if by "...hence has no zero-divisor $\neq 0$" is meant that all zero-devisors are zero. In that case $A/f^{-1} (q) $ would not be integral domain as expected.

Can somebody provide some insight or a proof of the statement ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how much algebra you've covered but here are some pointers to help you along

**Isomorphism to a subring**:

Let $f$ be ring hom from $A$ to $B$ as above, $g$ the quotient map from $B$ to $B/q$.

Compose $f$ and $g$ to get a map from $A$ to $B/q$.

Then find the Kernel of this map and use the 1st isomorphism theorem of rings.

**2nd part**:

Have you seen the result that an ideal $p$ of $R$ is prime iff $R/p$ is an integral domain?

We use this to do most of the work.

Hope these pointers help. :)))

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math in your posts here on MSE.